# Limiting Query Time of SelectSingleNode on multiple XPaths

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xpath

I have an XML file that I want to parse one of three different nodes out of into my C# program. Only one of these three different XPaths will be valid for any XML file, and each one is about as specific as possible. A sample XPath is below:

```
/ns:root/ns:foo/ns:bar[@barattr='{0}']/ns:foobar{1}/ns:{2} |                     
/ns:root/ns:foo/ns:bar[@barattr='{0}']/ns:{2} |                                
/ns:root/ns:foo/ns:bar[@barattr='{0}' and @{2}]
```

Note that these have formatters in them since in the code I am using String.Format to dynamically generate these queries.

My question, then, is what does SelectSingleNode do if the first XPath returns a node (i.e. there exists ns:root/ns:foo/ns:bar[@barattr='{0}']/ns:foobar{1}/ns:{2})? Will it still query all three XPaths and just return the first, or will it know to stop at that point? If it does still query all three, is there any way in C# or in XPath to signify to stop once a match is found?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not in a single XPath expression.

**You could try this, and must rely on the cleverness of the Optimizer being used:**

```
Exp1 | Exp2[not(Exp1)] | Exp3[not(Exp1) and not(Exp2)]
```

If the optimizer is a decent one (which in the case of .NET I believe it is), Exp2 will be evaluated only if Exp1 doesn't select a node, and Exp3 will be evaluated only if neither of Exp1 and Exp2 doesn't select a node.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been out of the office until today. Do we have any guarantees that a decent optimizer would also cache the result of Exp1, or would Exp1 be potentially rerun three times in this case, in order to ensure nothing was returned each time?

Comment: @DaveMcGinnis, The best answer is to try it. I am 99% sure that Saxon will optimize this. When I return home back from work I can make a small experiment -- but you can do yours now -- don't wait :)

Comment: So I went ahead and tried this out, and this seems to not work at all. Not only am I getting invalid results with the new query (something I'm still looking into, just in case that's the root cause of everything, however doubtful that is), but the times are all at least twice as slow as before. Surprised that MS doesn't optimize with this, but it's looking pretty grim that they do.

Comment: So I found the issue with the invalid queries, and while times have gotten better, they are still higher than the original times, so this is definitely not the solution for .NET XML at least. At this point, since it isn't a huge deal for us (we are still below 1ms per query on our sample XML files), I'm going to just give up unless someone else has a good way to handle this.

Comment: @DaveMcGinnis, I would be surprised .NET doesn't optimize this. Have you tried to take into account the time it takes to load/initialize the XSLT processor? This can be eliminated if you repeat the same query 100 or 1000 times and then divide the total time by 100 or by 1000, respectively.

Comment: Yes, so the test run that I did ran the same query function 100 times on two different functions. The XDocument is stored in a dictionary after the first time, so only the first time should see any penalty from loading the XDocument, but the averages of both queries were still higher by 50 - 150%.

Comment: So, do you confirm that the evaluation of the proposed single XPath expression takes significantly longer than just evaluating `Exp1`, or just evaluating `Exp|Exp2` ?

Comment: The proposed single XPath expression of `Exp1 | Exp2[not(Exp1)] | Exp3[not(Exp1) and not(Exp2)]` takes significantly longer than `Exp1 | Exp2 | Exp3`. Sorry for the confusion on that.

Comment: @DaveMcGinnis, THis means that no optimization is being done... So, on your platform one cannot use such tricks. Sorry. When I have time I will tst this with other XPath engines.